# Running Windows with an external ext4 drive caused the drive to become unreadable and now appears to be formatted with NTFS how do I recover my data

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, ext4

I used the Windows media creation tool to install Windows onto my USB. I installed Windows on a 120GB SSD in the system, along with that SSD is three other SSDs and two 12TB Western Digital Pro HDDs. One of the two HDDs, my primary drive with the majority of my data has been formatted with NTFS and the data is no longer accessible. My second drive appears to have had something done to it as well, but I can still access the data on it. I really don't know why Windows did this, I never touched the drives while I was in Windows. Am I going to have to use a data recovery tool or is there some way to just replace the formatting header on the drive? Here's some relevant information on the drive;

`fdisk /dev/sdX`

Both drives give error: `The size of this disk is 10.9 TiB (12000138625024 bytes). DOS partition table format cannot be used on drives for volumes larger than 2199023255040 bytes for 512-byte sectors. Use GUID partition table format (GPT).`

Only `/dev/sdb` gives: `The old ext4 signature will be removed by a write command.`

```
Primary Drive
Disk /dev/sda: 10.9 TiB, 12000138625024 bytes, 23437770752 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD121KFBX-68
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x12da48b1

Device     Boot Start    End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 104447  102400  50M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Secondary Drive
Disk /dev/sdb: 10.9 TiB, 12000138625024 bytes, 23437770752 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD121KFBX-68
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0b76fd8b
```

Comment: Use a data recovery tool. Windows can only read/write to ext4 partitions with some help,l such as free tool DiskGenius.

Comment: In my case, it looks like it will not be free. According to their product comparison lost partition recovery is only in the paid product.